# Python Dictionary, structure of folder and files but in two dictionaries

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, dictionary, directory

I am searching an algorithm to do a job. Basically I get an input from the user, the source directory. I want to create two different dictionaries, one that holds the subfolders of the folder one that holds the files of the folders.
For instance:

I have a folder 'folder' which inside includes a textfile named: log.txt and 3 sub-folders, folder1, folder2 and folder3. Inside the folder2 there is another text file named txt1.txt and another folder named subfolder and in this subfolder a picture named: pic.png

```
folder->log.txt, folder1, folder2->(txt.txt, subfolder->pic.png), folder3
```

What I want is a dictionary to looks like this:

```
folders = {'folder1':'', 'folder2': 'subfolder', folder3}
files = {'log.txt':'', 'txt.txt': 'folder2', 'pic.png':'folder2/subfolder'}
```

In general, what I need is a clear dictionary for the folders, and the subfolders so that to be easy after to create the folders and the subfolders correct. Then the dictionary of the files to be clear where the file owns. If you have other structure of the dictionary for the files nevermind, if you think is more easy and fast.
Thank you in advance.

Edit: I am running Mac OS X, with python 3

Edit 2:

```
dirs = [d for d in os.listdir(source) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(source, d))]

for folder in dirs:
    tmp_source = source + folder
    dirs2 = [d for d in os.listdir(tmp_source) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(tmp_source, d))]
    if dirs2 != []:
       print('Folder: ', dirs2, 'is not empty')

    dic[folder] = dirs2
```

Comment: Do you copy contents? If so, don't you [invent tar](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html)?

Comment: I want to do my way, and make use of dictionaries. I don't want a build-in function. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will recursively go through the root folder, and save the filenames from each folder (including the root folder) in a dictionary with key as folder path.

```
import os

root_folder = r'C:\Users\Steinar\Google Drive\Kode\Ymse\test\test'
content = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder):
    for subdir in dirs:
        content[os.path.join(root, subdir)] = []
    content[root] = files

# Print out the content dict    
for folder, filenames in content.items():
    print 'Folder: {}'.format(folder)
    print 'Filenames:'
    for filename in filenames:
        print '-> {}'.format(filename)
```

With the input as above, this scripts outputs the correct folder structure.

```
Folder: C:\Users\Steinar\Google Drive\Kode\Ymse\test\test\test2
Filenames:
-> test2.txt
Folder: C:\Users\Steinar\Google Drive\Kode\Ymse\test\test
Filenames:
-> test.txt
Folder: C:\Users\Steinar\Google Drive\Kode\Ymse\test\test\test2\test3\test4
Filenames:
Folder: C:\Users\Steinar\Google Drive\Kode\Ymse\test\test\test2\test3
Filenames:
-> test3.txt
```

If you want to rebuild the folder structure, you can just iterate over `content.keys()`, and create each folder.

Comment: Thank you, but I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/app.py", line 42, in <module>
    strr = os.path.walk(source_dir, store_fnames, None)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'walk'

Comment: Remember to parse your folder string like this: `r'C:\path\etc\'`, and `import os`.

Comment: I did, 
    source_dir = r'/Users/username/folder/'
    os.path.walk(source_dir, store_fnames, None)

Comment: `import os.path` will do

Comment: Well, then you should check your Python installation. This code is tested on Python 2.7.

Comment: Hey, I forget to point it out, I am using python3 on Mac OS X.

Comment: @alko Correct. I don't have time to update the answer atm, but the doc (http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/os.html) provides a good example.

Comment: Yes now works, but I cant see any result, basicly the procedure is not called up, we don't parse any parameters

Comment: @iCyprus read two attached links, in my and  Steinar Lima's comments.

Comment: I updated the answer, have a look at it. I haven't tested the code, but you should get a basic idea of the concept.

Comment: Thank you verymatch! Is know working good, but not as i describe on the original text, I mean this algorithm returns and the files as well, but also is not track and the empty subfolders of a subfolder.

Comment: I'm can't see what you are missing. What do you mean by "is not track"? As I don't currently have Python 3 installed, I can't test it for you. Are you trying to say that empty subfolders aren't included?

Comment: Yes, basicly is listing both folders and files, and just the folders with files in it.

Comment: Well, I updated the answer, but you should really try to do something yourself. If you play around with the code, it should not be hard to understand how this problem should be solved. Have you tried anything at all? If you need any more help, please provide us with some code that shows us that you at the very least have tried to understand our suggestions on your own.

Comment: Well, I edit my question, the algorithm can find the subfolders of a directory, and then to find if there is any subfolders in the subfolder of the folder, but this works just for two levels i mean:
can find that "folder" has folder1, folder2 subfolders and that the folder1 has the subfolder3 and that the folder2 has no other subfolders, but if the subfolder3 which is subfolder of the folder1 has other subfolders not work. Maybe a recursive can work with this?

Comment: os.walk() **does** go through the folder structure recursively. I downloaded and installed Python 3, and tested the code. It should now output what you expect.

Comment: The `for subdir in dirs:` loop is not adding anything, is it?